# Am I editing sources to my private bitbucket repo with a non authorized user?

Tags: bitbucket

I am really lost in my GIT today (and a newbee too)

I have 2 bitbucket users, and with user A I created a private repository online on the bitbucket site.

I've been pushing source changes to it, and all is well. (both via sourcetree and from the command line)

Until... I saw that the user pushing the changes is user B (I once created two accounts for bitbucket), and I did not grant him rights.

I probably am doing something wrong here, but I want to understand what that is.

When I do `git config user.name` I get 'userb'

When I look at the raw commit in the repo I see 'userb'

I have the access level : private repository

I did not send any invitation (afaik)

I don't know If I've ever granted userB all access to userA (Is that possible, and if so, where can I see that?)

When I look in the config file in the `.git` directory, I see no username

Is the user that pushes the code maybe another one then the committing user? Can it be that userB edits and commits, and userA pushes?

I don't think I've just experienced a security leak, but I do like to know why this happens.

Comment: the user that authored a commit doesn't need to be the same as the user that pushed that commit to a remote. In other words you probably made the commits with the email of user B locally and then pushed those commits as user A.

Comment: Hi @PeterT, is there a way to see via the git command line which user does the push?

Comment: (it's on a windows 10 computer)

Comment: I think bitbucket uses the url of the remote to determine that, so the username should be part of the url listed in `git remote -vv`

Comment: The url is this: `https://bitbucket.org/usera/reponame.git` , that doesn't look like any userb is in it